# How to do stateful list operations in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, iteration

I need an operation which iterates over a list and produces a new list, where the new list elements depend on all elements previously seen. To do this I would like to pass an accumulator/state from iteration to iteration.

Think for example of a list of tuples, where the components of a tuple can be "undefined". An undefined value shall assume the latest value of the same component earlier in the list, if any. So at any stage I will have a state of defined components, which I need to pass to the next iteration.

So with a list of type `[l]` and an accumulator/state of type `a` there will be a function of type

```
f :: a -> l -> (a,l)
```

i.e it spits out a new list element and a new accumulator.

Is there a function which allows simply applying f to a list? I looked at fold, scan and unfold, but none of them seem to do the trick.

Edit: While the state monad looks promising, I can only see how I would get the final state, but I fail to see how I would get the new list elements.

Comment: Note that, if you're trying to distinguish between _there is a value_ and _there is no value_, you should use `Maybe` rather than `undefined`.

Comment: Certainly - "Undefined" was casually written. The real datatype is an indication of change which three possible values, one of them is "no change".

Comment: This is just a perfectly normal `fold`, or I don't ubderstand something.

Comment: A fold collapses the list into a single "value", but I also want the new list elements. Hmm - I might let the state accumulate the new list elements (and not just the latest "value"). Is it that what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some standard functions you can use to do what you ask.

It sounds very much like you want `mapAccum`, so you just need to import `Data.List` and decide which way round you're accumulating. (I suspect you want `mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])`.)

### mapAccumL

```
import Data.List

data Instruction = NoChange | Reset | MoveBy Int

tell :: Int -> Instruction -> (Int,String) -- toy accumulating function
tell n NoChange = (n,"")
tell n Reset = (0,"Reset to zero")
tell n (MoveBy i) = (n+i,"Add "++show i++" to get "++ show (n+i))
```

which would give

```
ghci> mapAccumL tell 10 [MoveBy 5, MoveBy 3, NoChange, Reset, MoveBy 7]
(7,["Add 5 to get 15","Add 3 to get 18","","Reset to zero","Add 7 to get 7"])
```

### scanL

But maybe you don't need to use the full power of `mapAccum` because sometimes the accumulator is what you want in the new list, so `scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]` will do the trick

```
act :: Int -> Instruction -> Int
act n NoChange = n
act n Reset = 0
act n (MoveBy i) = n+i
```

like this:

```
ghci> scanl act 10 [MoveBy 5, MoveBy 3, NoChange, Reset, MoveBy 7]
[10,15,18,18,0,7]
```

### Definition for mapAccum

Anyway, here's how `mapAccumL` and `mapAccumR` are described in [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3amapAccumL):

```
mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
mapAccumL _ state []        =  (state, [])
mapAccumL f state (x:xs)    =  (finalstate,y:ys)
                           where (nextstate, y ) = f state x
                                 (finalstate,ys) = mapAccumL f nextstate xs
```

The `mapAccumL` function behaves like a combination of `map` and `foldl`; it applies a function to each element of a list, passing an accumulating parameter from left to right, and returning a final value of this accumulator together with the new list.

```
mapAccumR :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
mapAccumR _ state []        =  (state, [])
mapAccumR f state (x:xs)    =  (finalstate, y:ys)
                           where (finalstate,y ) = f nextstate x
                                 (nextstate, ys) = mapAccumR f state xs
```

The `mapAccumR` function behaves like a combination of `map` and `foldr`; it applies a function to each element of a list, passing an accumulating parameter from right to left, and returning a final value of this accumulator together with the new list.

Answer (score 6):

You want `mapM` in conjunction with the `State` monad where your accumulator `a` will be the `State`.  First, to see why you need `State`, just take your type signature and flip the order of arguments and results:

```
import Data.Tuple

f :: a -> l -> (a, l)

uncurry f :: (a, l) -> (a, l)

swap . uncurry f . swap :: (l, a) -> (l, a)

curry (swap . uncurry f . swap) :: l -> a -> (l, a)
```

Or you could just define `f` to already have the arguments and results in the right order, whichever you prefer.  I will call this swapped function `f'`:

```
f' :: l -> a -> (l, a)
```

Now lets add an extra set of parentheses around the right half of the type signature of `f'`:

```
f' :: l -> (a -> (l, a))
```

That part grouped in parentheses is a `State` computation where the state is `a` and the result is `l`.  So I will go ahead and convert it to the `State` type using the `state` function from `Control.Monad.Trans.State`:

```
state :: (a -> (l, a)) -> State a l
```

So the converted `f'` would look like this:

```
f'' :: l -> State a l
f'' = state . f'
```

However, the function you really want in the end is something of type:

```
final :: [l] -> a -> ([l], a)

-- which is really just:
state . final :: [l] -> State a [l]
```

So that means that I need some function that takes a `l -> State a l` and converts it to a `[l] -> State a [l]`.  This is precisely what `mapM` does, except that `mapM` works for any `Monad`, not just `State`:

```
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> ([a] -> m [b])
```

Notice how if we replace `m` with `State a`, and set `a` and `b` to `l`, then it has exactly the right type:

```
mapM :: (l -> State a l) -> ([l] -> State a [l])

f''' :: [l] -> State a [l]
f''' = mapM f''
```

Now we can unwrap the `State` using `runState` to get back a list-threading function of the appropriate type:

```
final :: [l] -> a -> ([l], a)
final = runState . f'''
```

So if we combine all those steps into one we get:

```
final = runState . mapM (state . f')
```

... where `f'` is your function written to swap the order of arguments and results.  If you choose not to modify your original function then the solution is slightly more verbose:

```
final = runState . mapM (state . uncurry (swap . curry f . swap))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the specifics of what you are actually trying to achieve, getting to an answer is a bit difficult. But it seems to be that if your `f` had the type:

```
f :: (a, [l]) -> l -> (a,l)
```

Then you could define a function, `f'`:

```
f' :: (a, [l]) -> l -> (a,l)
f' acc@(y, xs) x = (z, x':xs)
    where
        (z, x') = f acc
```

Which can then be used in a fold.

```
foldr f' (e, []) xs
```

The new signature of `f` allows it to have access to all preceding elements in the list, and  `f'` adds the new element from the call to `f` to the list.